# How to chain multiple sed commands properly

Tags: sed, command-line

I am trying to extract some info from a text block with markers like #@  and #@@.
Using the command below with the example file works, but when trying chain it with -e it does not work as expected.

Current command (not ideal)

```
sed -n "/^#@/,/#@@/p" file | sed 's/[#@]*//'
```

Reworked command ( does not work)

```
sed -en "/^#@/,/#@@/p" -e 's/[#@]*//' file
```

Desired output

```
text title
text line
text line
```

File format

```
#
#
#@ text title
#  text line
#  text line
#@@
#
```

What i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command

```
sed -en "/^#@/,/#@@/p" -e 's/[#@]*//' file
```

will likely error out, because `-en` tries to apply expression `n` to file `/^#@/,/#@@/p`. If you want to combine `-e` with other options, you must put the expression argument after the `-e` like `-ne "/^#@/,/#@@/p"` or separate them completely like `-n -e "/^#@/,/#@@/p"`

However it looks like you want to apply the substitute command *to the addressed lines* and **then** print them, which is really a single expression:

```
$ sed -n '/^#@/,/#@@/s/^#@*//p' file
 text title
  text line
  text line
```

To remove leading whitespace as well:

```
$ sed -n '/^#@/,/#@@/s/^#[@ ]*//p' file
text title
text line
text line
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems it cannot mix other options with -e switch

Comment: @ppk well you can't mix `-e` and `-n` like `-en 'expression'` because that tries to run `n` as an **e**xpression on file `expression`. You should however be able to do `-ne 'expression'`